# Sort list of objects by the return value of a method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class:

```
public class Student
{
  public string Name { get; set; }    

  public int FinalGrade(Course _course)
  {
     //...
  }
}
```

Now I have `List<Student> students` and a certain course `Course dotnet`. 
How can I get an ordered list of Students in this Course?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will order students by their grade in some course

```
var ordered = students.OrderBy(x=>x.FinalGrade(course));
```

`course` is course you mentioned

you can order it by second course:

```
var ordered = students.OrderBy(x=>x.FinalGrade(course)).ThenBy(x=>x.FinalGrade(course2));
```

Comment: Can I order the ordered list `ordered` again by another object `course2`?

Comment: @enb081 yes, I'll create example